# How to add some data to an Enum in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented-design, python-3.x, enum

I have a class that I use to define different types of plots I am performing

```
class MyPlots(Enum):
  STANDARDSCALE = "standard"
  LOGSCALE = "log"
```

there are default values associated with the coordinates I usually plot with, i.e., in my code I have parts like

```
  ...
  if self._plottype==MyPlots.STANDARDSCALE:
    xlimits = [math.e, math.e**2]

  if self._plottype==MyPlots.LOGSCALE:
    xlimits = [1,2]
  ...
```

I am wondering about what would be the best way to refactor this code, i.e., writing an abstract class

```
class PlotTypeWorks(ABC):
  xlimits
  @virutalmethod
  def __init__(self, type : MyPlots):
    """ Sets limits """

class Plot(PlotTypeWorks):
  def __init__(self, type : MyPlots):
    self._plottype = type
    if self._plottype==MyPlots.STANDARDSCALE:
      self.xlimits = [math.e, math.e**2]
    if self._plottype==MyPlots.LOGSCALE:
      self.xlimits = [1,2]
```

or having `PlotStandard` and `PlotLog` classes.

I want the code to be fast and easy to read at the same time. What I am concerned about, is that with different classes (`PlotStandard` and `PlotLog`) the code might soon be overcrowded with plots with different parameters (hard to read). From the other side, with only one class, I might be calling a lot of checks (`if self._plottype==X`) that might just slow my code when I will create thousands of those classes.

Is there a solution with the perks of both? i.e., less checks and more readability?

Comment: I fail to see how the check would be the bottleneck that slows your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple different ways you can build that information directly into the enum definitions:

1. use the limit values instead of the string for the enum value;
2. add the limit values to the string value

(1) would look like:

```
class MyPlots(Enum):
    STANDARDSCALE = math.e, math.e**2
    LOGSCALE = 1, 2

xlimits = self._plottype.value
```

(2) would look like

```
class MyPlots(Enum):
    STANDARDSCALE = "standard", (math.e, math.e**2)
    LOGSCALE = "log", (1, 2)
    #
    def __new__(cls, value, limits):
        member = object.__new__(cls)
        member._value_ = value
        member.limits = limits
        return member

xlimits = self._plottype.limits
```

In use, (2) would look like:

```
>>> list(MyPlots)
[<MyPlots.STANDARDSCALE: 'standard'>, <MyPlots.LOGSCALE: 'log'>]

>>> MyPlots.LOGSCALE.limits
(1, 2)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example on how you would then create an object of the second kind? It is very interesting but it looks like you should provide value and limits in the initializer (is `__new__` the same as `__init__`?)

Comment: @LaCartuccia: No, `__new__` creates and returns an object while `__init__` works with the already created object.  Typically, mutable objects do their setup work in `__init__` and immutable objects do it in `__new__`.  It is possible to split the work and have both a `__new__` and an `__init__`, but in this case that doesn't provide any benefit.

Comment: @LaCartuccia: Not sure what you mean by "an object of the second kind".  I added an example use of my number (2) -- hopefully that helps.

Comment: Oh I see thank you.
And yes, I meant number (2).
So the idea is that limits is now a `static member`, right?
I had a look at the documentation and they have an example for Planet

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#planet

From what I understood `__init__` should be fine too

Comment: @LaCartuccia: It depends on the goal -- in my (2) if the `__new__` wasn't there then the value would be the entire assignment `"log", (1,2)`.

Comment: I don't know how related it is, but I found out that for pickling your approach (`__new__` instead of `__init__`) is extremely more convenient.
I guess that you know something about that
https://groups.google.com/g/dev-python/c/7WhCs5EdfLM/m/EdIDkkzunUkJ?pli=1